# Foreach Loop returning data as result

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following `Model` and I am unsure how to return the result so that I can select the needed row like this `$this->model_name->function_name->function_value` - or is there a better way?

**Model:**

```
function companyDetails()
    {
       $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');

        $this->db->from('core');

        $query = $this->db->get(1);

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            echo $row->coreCompanyName;
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you would call your model function something like `getCompanyDetailsByID()`, where you pass in the unique identifier, and it returns a single result object accordingly:

```
<?php
function getCompanyDetailsByID($id)
{
    $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
    $this->db->where('coreCompanyID', $id);
    return $this->db->get('core')->first_row();
}
```

Replace "coreCompanyID" with your primary column name.

**ADDITION:**

Here's how you would get all the companies' info:

```
<?php
function getCompanyDetails()
{
    $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
    return $this->db->get('core')->result();
}

// And then in your controller:
function display()
{
    $this->load->model('core');
    $companies = $this->core->getCompanyDetails();
    // Here's where you would probably load the data into a view
    foreach ($companies as $company)
    {
        echo $company->coreCompanyName.'<br />';
    }
}
```

**FINAL ANSWER! :P**

```
<?php
function companyDetails()
{
    static $details;

    if ( !$details)
    {
        $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
        $this->db->where('coreCompanyID', $id);
        $details = $this->db->get('core')->first_row();
    }

    return $details;
}
```

Now you can make multiple calls to that function, and it will only hit your database once, for example:

```
<?php
echo $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
// do stuff
echo $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactName;
// more stuff
echo $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactEmail;
```

All that only hit your database once.

Comment: But then would I know have to pass an id into the model?

Comment: How else would you know which result you want?  If you want to get all the companies, that's a different story, and I'd need to change the answer.

Comment: but there is only going to be one company in this db so I just wanted to extract the data

Comment: Ah. Makes sense now.  What do you want to do with the data?  Returning `$this->db->get(1)->first_row()` is all you need from the model.  It seems odd you have a separate column in the "core" table for this stuff; you might revisit your schema...

Comment: Thanks,  Am I able to do $this->core_model->getCompanyDetails->coreCompanyName;  or similar it will just limit the need for another function that currently will only house 3 rows.

Comment: You could do `$this->core_model->getCompanyDetails()->coreCompanyName`, but it will hit your database on every call to that function if you're not careful.  There's a clever way around that.  I'll update the answer